# How can I determine what's a better configuration for my app?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, postgresql-performance, postgresql-12

I'm currently using Postgres 12 on AWS RDS and am using their default configuration for the database.

I use a gem called PgHero that advises me to use PGTune to improve the efficiency of the database.  After inserting my inputs on `https://pgtune.leopard.in.ua/`

```
# DB Version: 12
# OS Type: linux
# DB Type: web
# Total Memory (RAM): 7 GB
# CPUs num: 2
# Data Storage: ssd
```

It gives me the advice to update my DB configuration to:

```
max_connections = 200  # AWS has: LEAST({DBInstanceClassMemory/9531392},5000)
shared_buffers = 1792MB  # AWS has {DBInstanceClassMemory/32768}
effective_cache_size = 5376MB # AWS has {DBInstanceClassMemory/16384}
maintenance_work_mem = 448MB  # AWS has GREATEST({DBInstanceClassMemory*1024/63963136},65536)
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.7  # AWS has 0.9
wal_buffers = 16MB # AWS is not set
default_statistics_target = 100  # AWS is not set
random_page_cost = 1.1  # AWS is not set
effective_io_concurrency = 200 # AWS is not set
work_mem = 9175kB # AWS is not set
min_wal_size = 1GB  # AWS is 192MB
max_wal_size = 4GB  # AWS is 2048MB
max_worker_processes = 2 # AWS is 8
max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 1 # AWS is not set
max_parallel_workers = 2 # AWS is not set
max_parallel_maintenance_workers = 1 # AWS is not set
```

I'm not sure whether to use PGTune or just leave RDS defaults?  How does one typically determine if there is performance updates? Am I in over my head?

Comment: The purpose of performance tuning is to address specific performance problems, one at a time. What is your performance problem, and how would you know when it is solved? A sample problem statement might sound like this: "Query X often runs for 5 minutes. I want it to complete in under 30 seconds."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct configuration depends on your hardware, your database size and your workload, none of which we know.

Tune conservatively at first, setting `shared_buffers` and `work_mem` to some reasonable values based on database size and workload, and setting `maintenance_work_mem`, `effective_cache_size`, `effective_io_concurrency` and `random_page_cost` according to your hardware. Finally,  configure logging.

Adjust these and other parameters based on the findings from a realistic load test.

Comment: Sounds like I'm in over my head at the moment. Thank you.

Comment: We could easily know the hardware type if we asked what type of instance it was. I'd love to see some real-world stats for t3 and t2 instances for example. especially on things like "random_page_cost"